# jQuery find an element by its index

Tags: jquery

If I have a selection

```
<div id="container">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
    <div>item 4</div>
</div>
```

How can I select a div by it's index?

For example, I'd like to select item 2...by using index = 1, not by 'div' or text contains "item 2"

Comment: man try googling a little before posting question.. check this http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: I think you're looking for the `.children()` selector ... see my detailed answer below.

Comment: If you go to http://api.jquery.com/ and type *"index"* into the search field at the top, the API will be narrowed to the point where it is trivial to find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either of these:

- [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) - This is the getter. Get the index of a given element, and apply logic, based on it.
- [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)- These can be used to get an element from a given jQuery collection
- [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) - Select an element which is the *n*th **child (!!)** element, respective to the parent.

In your case, `eq` or `:nth-child` are suitable. Eg:

```
var item1 = $('#container > :nth-child(1)');  // parent > child (=first child)
var item2 = $('#container').children().eq(1); // Zero-based indexes
```

Comment: ''As of jQuery 3.4, the `:eq` pseudo-class is deprecated. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using .eq().'' see [official :eq documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `eq()` method.

```
$("#container > div").eq(1)
```

You can even use `:eq(1)` pseudo selector.

```
$("#container > div:eq(1)")
```

`.eq(index)` reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

`:eq(index)` selects the element at index n within the matched set.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#container div").eq(1) // zero-based, so will select 'item 2'
```

Comment: He specifically said, "not by DIV". (But I'll remove it as there are several similar answers and I'm not downvoting them all. Besides that, it looks like Rob W has replaced his answer with code from those who were actually listening to the question.)  
EDIT: Did it not remove the downvote?

Comment: @TimothyAaron That's an accusation with no grounds. My original answer was something like "Use either `index`, `eq` or `:nth-child`.". These contained the basics. Later, I expanded my answer with the implementation of these methods. As for "EDIT": You cannot remove a vote when a post hasn't been edited for a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container').children().eq(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning you could use the nth-child selector:

```
 var item = $('#container div:nth-child(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector like below,

```
   $('#container div:eq(2)') //will return you div with item 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container').children().eq(2);
```

Comment: Also, remember to subtract 1 from the item you want, as `.eq()` is zero-based. (So, you'd do `.eq(1)` for the second item.)