# Access multiple items with same name in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web

Using the web developer console I can access the content of the first item of particular class like this from the web console:

```
$(".license-box pre").text();
```

However, what if there is more than one object with the name "pre" which are members of the class "license-box"? How do I access instance 1, 2, n etc?

I am NOT asking how to iterate through a list of class members. I am asking how to access the Nth member of the list, which is a different question. This is not a duplicate of the marked post. It is a duplicate of the post Felix King linked below, so it should be retagged correctly to point to Felix's item.

Solution as posted below: use the `.eq()` method.

Comment: What is `$`? jQuery? You may want to read through a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: @squint the OP has almost 5000 rep

Comment: @Pointy: Should I offer him my congratulations? Or should I take his 5k rep to mean he should know that he ought to do basic research first?

Comment: What LOL, yeah maybe OP is really good with other languages, but yeah this is pretty basic.

Comment: @squint ha no I just meant that the OP has had plenty of time to absorb the ways of SO already. Agreed that this is a question whose answers are sitting right there in the jQuery API docs (assuming that `$` is jQuery, which is a safe bet but still a bet).

Comment: Yeah, since someone else decided it was jQuery and added the tag, I figured I'd go ahead and grab one of the dupes.

Comment: OP: By the way you are not accessing only one when using `$(".license-box pre").text();`. You are basically doing `document.getElementsByClassName` returning a Nodelist object. You can iterate over them like in plain javascript.

Comment: Better duplicate now: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9231096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the collection of items with `.each()`:

```
$(".license-box pre").each(function() {
  console.log("this <pre> contains: " + $(this).text());
});
```

The callback to `.each()` is passed the index, which would let you do something like act only on the even-indexed elements:

```
$(".license-box pre").each(function(index) {
  if ((index & 1) === 0)
    console.log("even <pre>: " + $(this).text());
});
```

If you know which one you want, you can use `.eq()`:

```
var third = $(".license-box pre").eq(3);
```

You can do a lot of stuff right in the selector itself. If you want to do something to every 3rd `<pre>` you could do this:

```
$(".license-box pre:nth-child(3n)").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

(The `nth-child()` selector here would make sense when the `<pre>` elements are the direct children of the "license-box" container, because the semantics have to do with each element's sibling relationships.)

Comment: The .eq method is what I needed: $(".license-box pre").eq(1).text();

Comment: @TylerDurden you can also do `$(".license-box pre:eq(1)").text()`

Comment: Using `.eq(1)` avoids the skank of non-standard selectors.

Comment: @sixfingeredman yes that's certainly true

Answer (score -1):

Like this? [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var res = [];

$(".license-box pre").each(function(){
    res.push($(this).text()); // or alert($(this).text());
});

console.log(res);
```

Now, if you want text of `n`th instance, simply do:

```
alert(res[n - 1]);
```